# Oracleのストアドファンクションがいつ誰から実行されたか調べる術はありませんか？

Tags: oracle

Oracle18cを利用しています。
既に作成されているsooni.TESTFUNC() がいつ、誰からどれくらいの頻度で
実行されているのか調べたいです。
条件として調査対象のファンクションは現行のまま修正したくありません。
ファイングレイン監査の利用を試みたのですが、どうやらこちらはストアドファンクションや
ストアドプロシージャは調べられそうにありませんでした。
何か良いアイデアお持ちの方あったら教えてください。
「そんな事はできないよ」というご意見もありがたいので、このあたり
ご存じの方あったら教えてください。